# how does ubunto sound output work?

Tags: sound

When I plug my 3.5mm cord into the jack on my HP running Ubuntu, going to an external speaker (a Braven of some type), sound keeps coming out of my weak pc speakers.

Fair enough- something is mis-configured I assume. I check sound settings and Output Device options in particular. The only output device that shows up is the built in speaker. Fair enough, we'll figure it out.

I plug in my headphones though, and they work. They make a new output option populate in settings menu. Also fwiw my external speaker works in my other computer, so it's not that.

I'm not as interested in getting it working, as I am wondering how this works! My mind is blown because I always assumed the operating system was "dumb" to what's on the other side of a 3.5 jack. Do you mean to tell me the computer can sense what speaker the cord is going to, that the line is duplex, and programmatically decide to recognize it or not? For years I've been trained to believe that if you put a 3.5mm cable into a jack, it takes over, and if nothing else will make the speakers go mute (but that you can ignore it). This is a new pattern to me, that I didn't even know was possible.

How does ubuntu detect what's on the other end of the jack? Why does it care what's there (what did the devs have in mind)? Why not just port the music to that jack if something is in it, if just to make it mute as that's convention? But mostly how does it know and why can't it sense my speaker? Is it because it's too old and low tech?

I love technological advancement but sometimes I think devices are too smart and over-engineered for our own pleasure and good but still I'm really curious about this technology and this pattern

Comment: Are the speakers powered?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.